# How to make any ip address connect to the remote MySQL server?

Tags: java, php, mysql, database

Reason for asking the question:

For my third year minor project I am making an instant messenger type of application. The MySQL server for which will reside on my college's server. I have made the application in java and I am using mySQL for the back-end database.

Problem/Question:

My problem is that when I will distribute the application to my fellow students, the mysql server will be transferred to the college's server(currently everything is on my home computer, since I am developing right now), but then what I am supposed to do so that to every application remotely will be able to access this db on my college server.

I will be more specific:

This the basic code I am using currently:

> Connection o =
>   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db","root","pass");

I know when i will finally deploy the mysql db onto the server the localhost shall be replaced by the server's ip address(in each of the applications), but today when I tried to do this, I always got the error that:

"null message from server host 'theremoteip' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server"

So i went to the mysql server and applied:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY '%';
```

then i got this error:

Access denied for user 'root'@'theremoteipaddress' (using password: YES)

So, i figured that in the 'mysql' database root user may be assigned to only certain host addresses, i may be wrong but i think this is the problem.

So, I humbly request all of the veterans present on this community to please help me, I am new to all of this and I apologize if this question has an obvious answer and I didn't knew it.

Thank you for reading and please help me.
Again, the question is how I can make all the remote applications that I distribute among students to connect to the MYSQL database.

Comment: You should not have the clients connecting directly to your MySQL server, you should build a java server app that your clients connect to that intern connects to your MySQL database.

Comment: Thank you cmorrissey, really thank you!!! I understand your point but then how will i make the client connect to the java server app, are you pointing by utilizing sockets, I am really new to all this please don't get mad at me If I asked a stupid question.

Comment: A thin API bridge layer is the only reasonable way to do this. You can use any programming language to do this, and the easiest design is one that just ships XML or JSON over HTTP. MySQL is fairly secure, but isn't intended to be exposed to the public internet where it could be probed or attacked. HTTP is much more easily secured and buffered from attacks.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/259777-a-simple-chat-program-with-clientserver-gui-optional/ here is a quick tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably for security reasons, root is allowed to login only from the same machine on which mysql server is running(or from listed ip addresses). If you ssh to your server and open mysql from there you should be able to change the permissions for your user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But then I'll have to do that for every user I distribute the application to and the ip address of the remote machine can always change, so how will I monitor that.

Comment: You have DB account for your application, not for each user of your application. It is your code that access the DB not the real users, so each instance of aplication would typically used the same DB user name. Instead of IP addresses you could use domain name which stayes same. You cannot monitor it, you provide a configuration that points to necessary resources (DB, WS) and if something change you have to update that configuration. Also I dont think your clients should talk to DB directly but rather to some WebApp

Comment: Got it!! Thank you so much!!! I got your point!!! You mean making a java program residing on the server that communicates with the mysql and establishing a connection between the client application and that java program right??